# Reset Password in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am writing a script in which user can reset his password.

User will get an email  like

[My example](http://example.com/resetpassword/email_token)

when user will click on that link. a form will open 
and user can enter a new password. 
this is my route code

```
app.get('/resetpassword/:token', function (req, res, next) {
        var fileLocation = path.resolve(__dirname + '/../public/resetpassword.html');
        console.log(fileLocation);
        res.sendfile(fileLocation);
    });

    app.post('/setnewpassword', function(req,res,next){
                console.dir(req.body);
    });
```

and my html is there

```
   <form action="/setnewpassword" method="POST">
        <div>
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Now problem is that i am not getting params under **app.post('/setnewpassword'**

Any idea? how to get params under setnewpassword.

I want to use POST method only

Comment: are you using bodyparser to parse POST params ?

Comment: how to use that. i have no idea

Comment: Tell us more about your code, are you using express?
did you check the request going from the browser? are the params part of it?
if yes then what are the headers of the req? is it application/json?

Comment: Why are you writing your own password reset scripts?  There are many services and libraries that can automate that for you in a few minutes and keep you from introducing a vulnerability into your code.  Stormpath has a nice node.js integration, Parse is good if you're doing mobile, etc.  You have many options. *I work at Stormpath*

Answer (score 0):

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Make sure you place the code before your post handlers.

Comment: Not working. i use this code
app.use(bodyParser);
 app.get('/resetpassword/:token', function (req, res, next) {
  var fileLocation = path.resolve(__dirname + '/../public/resetpassword.html');
  console.log(fileLocation);
  res.sendfile(fileLocation);
 });
 
 app.post('/setnewpassword', function(req,res,next){
    console.dir(req.params);
 });

Comment: you need to check the req.body not req.params

Comment: in request body. there is only one field  password. i need url param too

Comment: you need to change your 
<form action="/setnewpassword" method="POST"> 
to <form action="/setnewpassword/:token" method="POST">

Answer (score 0):

First add bodyparser middleware to your app.js

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
.....
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

Then in your handler, access form parameters like this:

```
var password = req.params.password || '';
```

If you use REST client, set the Content-Type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Answer (score 0):

you have said **"you are not  getting params under app.post('/setnewpassword'"** but params available in

```
app.get('/resetpassword/:token', function (req, res, next)
```

you need to send this param to html page and then from html page to

```
app.post('/setnewpassword/:token',function(req,res){
});
```

Comment: Can u pls tell me how to send param to html page

Comment: Now you need to pass it to /setnewpassword api call .

Comment: you could pass it as params or in body along with password. If I am not wrong you need to verify token first , if token exist then only you will aloow user to reset password

Comment: ok, if i verify the token first. then how i will get which user is active for resting the passworf

Comment: How to pass it as a params. please tell

Comment: you could use javascript method get token from url and then submit the form data using ajax call including token and password

Comment: Gets the current page URL:
var url = window.location.href;
var token = url.lastIndexOf("/");

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/changepass' , function (req, res, next) {
     if (newpass !== newpassconfirm) {
        throw new Error('password and confirm password do not match');
     }

     var user = req.user;

     user.pass = newpass;

     user.save(function(err){
         if (err) { next(err) }
         else {
             res.redirect('/account');
         }
     })
});
```